# How to make Android CardView visible when using Dark Theme

Tags: android, android-cardview, material-components-android, android-dark-theme

I am investigating CardView and Dark Theme in my current Android application

The majority of my application works as expected when Dark Mode is enables except for the CardViews.

my Gradle resembles this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.application.investigation"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

  implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

My Theme is as follows:-

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/design_default_color_error</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

My CardView layout resembles this:-

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_films_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:context=".films.Films">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_films_film"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorSurface"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_padding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/film_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_heading"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Title Of Film" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/film_director"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            tools:text="Director Of Film" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/film_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@dimen/line_spacing_item"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            tools:text="Description Of Film" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The CardViews are "perfect" in Light Mode, however when I switch to Dark Mode the CardViews are not visible.

What mistake(s) have I made ?

Is it possible to employ CardViews in Dark Mode and see them?

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using the `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.*` theme use the `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` instead of `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`.

The `MaterialCardView` extends the `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` and uses a different style: `Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView`.

Comment: This change makes no difference

Comment: @Hector try to change the cardBackgroundColor attribute

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.*`, the cardView widget must use `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` class instead of `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`

So, in your xml, inflate `card_view:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorSurface"` instead of `card_view:cardBackgroundColor="?android:attr/colorBackground"`, as Material Guideline state that

> Additionally, the Material Android library provides PrimarySurface styles for components that act as large surfaces and commonly use colorPrimary for their background in light theme. These styles will automatically switch between the component's primary colored style in light theme and surface colored style in dark theme.

reference : [material.io](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark)